# Which way is best to use IMG tag and CSS background image for gaming

Tags: jquery, css, html

I am creating simple drag and drop game in HTML5, CSS3 and jQuery. For this game I am using number of images as background image to a seperate div with mouse down, mouse move & mouse up event.

HTML Code is:

```
<div class="car"></div>
<div class="bus"></div>
<div class="bike"></div>
```

Css Code is:

```
.car{ background-image: url("../images/car.png");}
.bus{ background-image: url("../images/bus.png");}
.bike{ background-image: url("../images/bike.png");}
```

I need to use the image as dynamic for different game ex:- flowers.

I am using JSON data for dynamic image urls.

I used to change the images using jQuery as background-image. By using this way bg image getting late to load and the div showing with empty space. I can't predict load complete event for the bg image.

Is any event is there for getting CSS bg image load success or using `<img>` tag is best?

Comment: see his work http://stevepapa.com/how-to-load-images-beautifully-on-your-website-using-jquery-and-9-lines-of-code and read the problem, it might help you

Comment: Thanks Saravanan. I am using the images as CSS background to a DIV element. For this "loadComplete" event will get dispatch?

Comment: You seem to have misspelled 'image', repeatedly.

Comment: Thanks David, for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pre-load all the images that would be used as CSS background image. Use this jquery [library](https://github.com/zoltan-dulac/imageCache) which would be useful and has the callback for imageLoaded.

Put a preloader until all the images are loaded and show your page once the images has been loaded. Now if you change the CSS background image using jquery it will be loaded without any issues.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion (+1). I will try image catch jquery library